# geckofx button click

Tags: geckofx

i have integrated skybound gecckofx into my application . i am able to fill up textbox

```
GeckoElement username = null; 
username = checkDoc.GetElementById("ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_txtUserName");
username.SetAttribute("value", "myemail@gmail.com");
```

but i am unable to click the button

```
GeckoElement button1 = null;
button1 = checkDoc.GetElementById("ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_lbtnLogin");
button.click() // there is no function by the name on click on the button
```

Comment: Document.getHtmlelementbyid(string id); or so has the click function.

Comment: i have checked and there is no click event on GeckoElement . i am using skybound.gecko dll as a refrence

Comment: Which version do you use? Download the latest and there will one Event https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-18.0/downloads/GeckoFx-Windows-18.0-0.1.zip

Answer (score 6):

Check if you have the class GeckoInputElement. If no then probably you need Skybount.Com libraries. Or you can use newest versio of gecko fx. Use GeckoFX 21 with xulrunner 21.
you can get from ftp.mozila.org

in geckofx 21 you can try this code

```
GeckoButtonElement button = new GeckoButtonElement(_webBrowser.Document.getElementById("your_button_id").DomObject);
button.Click();
```

So simple!

Also you can use GeckoInputElement to input you email address to the html element like this

```
GeckoInputElement username = new GeckoInputElement(checkDoc.GetElementById("ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_txtUserName");
.DomObject);
username.Value = "myemail@gmail.com"
```

Τέλος! (Finish)

Comment: Can you help me find a direct link to get these updated versions of GeckoFX and xulrunner? I am having trouble finding it.

Comment: Here you can found all versions of xulrunner http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/ and GeckFX here https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-18.0/overview

Answer (score 1):

I have done with this way

```
 Gecko.GeckoHtmlElement Btn = (Gecko.GeckoHtmlElement)browse.DomDocument.GetElementById("btnPrint");               
 Btn.Click();
```

//browse = the name of `Gecko` browser control

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried something like this?

```
function performClick(buttonElement)
{
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    evt.initEvent("click", true, true);
    buttonElement.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
'geckowebbrowser for any element click function
Dim element = geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("someid")
Dim Clickelement As GeckoHtmlElement = CType(element,GeckoHtmlElement)
Clickelement.Click()
```

Comment: While this can be a valid answer it does not provide any explanation to the user how and why it works.

Comment: hi,i am a programer vb,php,android and nodejs